# Constructing Soap Request in PHP

Tags: php, soap

New to soap, I've used soapUI (http://www.soapui.org) to test the service I need to access and determined that I need the soap request to look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:_5=mynamespace>
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <_5:GetStaff>
      <_5:Request>
        <_5:SourceCredentials>
          <_5:SourceName>name</_5:SourceName>
          <_5:Password>pword</_5:Password>
          <_5:SiteIDs>
            <_5:int>num</_5:int>
          </_5:SiteIDs>
        </_5:SourceCredentials>
      </_5:Request>
    </_5:GetStaff>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

where mynamespace, name, pword, and num are all placeholders.  I just need to construct this request in PHP.  This is my latest attempt:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
require_once('nusoap.php');

$wsdl = ...;
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

/*
echo("\nDumping client object:\n");
var_dump($client);

echo("\nDumping client object functions:\n");
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
*/

try {
  $credentials = new SoapVar(array(
                                   'SourceName'=>name,
                                   'Password'=>pword,
                                   'SiteIDs'=>num
                                  ),
                             SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
                             type1,
                             mynamespace
                         );
  $request = new SoapVar(array('SourceCredentials'=>$credentials),
                         SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
                         type2,
                         mynamespace
                        );
  $result = $client->GetStaff(new SoapParam($request, "Request"));
  echo $result;
}
catch (SoapFault $fault) {
  trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
}

print "<pre>\n";
print "Request :\n".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) ."\n";
print "Response:\n".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse())."\n";
print "</pre>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Take my word for it that type1 is the appropriate type for the SourceCredentials tag and that type2 is the appropriate type for the Request tag.

When I open this file in a browser*, absolutely nothing shows up.  When the commented lines are uncommented, I can see the dump of the object (although I have no idea how to go about interpreting the dump), but the object functions are NOT displayed.

Does this sound like the `SoapClient` itself isn't set up properly, or is the error in the construction of the parameters for the soap call?

*Clarification: I've named this file "`index.php`," and in a browser I'm navigating to the directory in which this file is located (it is a sub-directory of my `public_html` directory).

Dumping client object: `object(soapclient)#1 (48) { ["username"]=> string(0) "" ["password"]=> string(0) "" ["authtype"]=> string(0) "" ["certRequest"]=> array(0) { } ["requestHeaders"]=> bool(false) ["responseHeaders"]=> string(0) "" ["responseHeader"]=> NULL ["document"]=> string(0) "" ["endpoint"]=> string(64) "foobar.axmx?wsdl" ["forceEndpoint"]=> string(0) "" ["proxyhost"]=> bool(false) ["proxyport"]=> bool(false) ["proxyusername"]=> bool(false) ["proxypassword"]=> bool(false) ["portName"]=> string(0) "" ["xml_encoding"]=> string(0) "" ["http_encoding"]=> bool(false) ["timeout"]=> int(0) ["response_timeout"]=> int(30) ["endpointType"]=> string(4) "soap" ["persistentConnection"]=> bool(false) ["defaultRpcParams"]=> bool(false) ["request"]=> string(0) "" ["response"]=> string(0) "" ["responseData"]=> string(0) "" ["cookies"]=> array(0) { } ["decode_utf8"]=> bool(true) ["operations"]=> array(0) { } ["curl_options"]=> array(0) { } ["bindingType"]=> string(0) "" ["use_curl"]=> bool(false) ["fault"]=> NULL ["faultcode"]=> NULL ["faultstring"]=> NULL ["faultdetail"]=> NULL ["title"]=> string(6) "NuSOAP" ["version"]=> string(5) "0.9.5" ["revision"]=> string(18) "$Revision: 1.123 $" ["error_str"]=> string(0) "" ["debug_str"]=> string(305) "2011-05-12 17:10:31.480099 soapclient: ctor wsdl= timeout=0 response_timeout=30 endpoint=string(64) "foobar.asmx?wsdl" 2011-05-12 17:10:31.480593 soapclient: instantiate SOAP with endpoint at foobar.asmx?wsdl " ["charencoding"]=> bool(true) ["debugLevel"]=> int(9) ["XMLSchemaVersion"]=> string(32) "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ["soap_defencoding"]=> string(10) "ISO-8859-1" ["namespaces"]=> array(4) { ["SOAP-ENV"]=> string(41) "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ["xsd"]=> string(32) "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ["xsi"]=> string(41) "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ["SOAP-ENC"]=> string(41) "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" } ["usedNamespaces"]=> array(0) { } ["typemap"]=> array(6) { ["http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"]=> array(43) { ["string"]=> string(6) "string" ["boolean"]=> string(7) "boolean" ["float"]=> string(6) "double" ["double"]=> string(6) "double" ["decimal"]=> string(6) "double" ["duration"]=> string(0) "" ["dateTime"]=> string(6) "string" ["time"]=> string(6) "string" ["date"]=> string(6) "string" ["gYearMonth"]=> string(0) "" ["gYear"]=> string(0) "" ["gMonthDay"]=> string(0) "" ["gDay"]=> string(0) "" ["gMonth"]=> string(0) "" ["hexBinary"]=> string(6) "string" ["base64Binary"]=> string(6) "string" ["anyType"]=> string(6) "string" ["anySimpleType"]=> string(6) "string" ["normalizedString"]=> string(6) "string" ["token"]=> string(6) "string" ["language"]=> string(0) "" ["NMTOKEN"]=> string(0) "" ["NMTOKENS"]=> string(0) "" ["Name"]=> string(0) "" ["NCName"]=> string(0) "" ["ID"]=> string(0) "" ["IDREF"]=> string(0) "" ["IDREFS"]=> string(0) "" ["ENTITY"]=> string(0) "" ["ENTITIES"]=> string(0) "" ["integer"]=> string(7) "integer" ["nonPositiveInteger"]=> string(7) "integer" ["negativeInteger"]=> string(7) "integer" ["long"]=> string(7) "integer" ["int"]=> string(7) "integer" ["short"]=> string(7) "integer" ["byte"]=> string(7) "integer" ["nonNegativeInteger"]=> string(7) "integer" ["unsignedLong"]=> string(0) "" ["unsignedInt"]=> string(0) "" ["unsignedShort"]=> string(0) "" ["unsignedByte"]=> string(0) "" ["positiveInteger"]=> string(0) "" } ["http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema"]=> array(11) { ["i4"]=> string(0) "" ["int"]=> string(7) "integer" ["boolean"]=> string(7) "boolean" ["string"]=> string(6) "string" ["double"]=> string(6) "double" ["float"]=> string(6) "double" ["dateTime"]=> string(6) "string" ["timeInstant"]=> string(6) "string" ["base64Binary"]=> string(6) "string" ["base64"]=> string(6) "string" ["ur-type"]=> string(5) "array" } ["http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"]=> array(11) { ["i4"]=> string(0) "" ["int"]=> string(7) "integer" ["boolean"]=> string(7) "boolean" ["string"]=> string(6) "string" ["double"]=> string(6) "double" ["float"]=> string(6) "double" ["dateTime"]=> string(6) "string" ["timeInstant"]=> string(6) "string" ["base64Binary"]=> string(6) "string" ["base64"]=> string(6) "string" ["ur-type"]=> string(5) "array" } ["http://soapinterop.org/xsd"]=> array(1) { ["SOAPStruct"]=> string(6) "struct" } ["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"]=> array(3) { ["base64"]=> string(6) "string" ["array"]=> string(5) "array" ["Array"]=> string(5) "array" } ["http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "Map" } } ["xmlEntities"]=> array(5) { ["quot"]=> string(1) """ ["amp"]=> string(1) "&" ["lt"]=> string(1) "<" ["gt"]=> string(1) ">" ["apos"]=> string(1) "'" } }`

Comment: Have you checked your HTML source code? XML will sometimes not show up when the browser interprets it as HTML. Show us the dump of the object.

Comment: @powtac: Hopefully the clarification I added is helpful.  Sorry I thought I could put the object dump in this comment, but it's far too large; I'm adding that to my post now.

Comment: Have you considered not including *nusoap*, or is that a requirement of your PHP version? I've recently done some soap work in PHP and the nusoap include wasn't necessary, and in fact may have confused things based on me having outdated versions lying around.

Comment: @Femi: not a requirement, just something I added in the attempt to get things working.  Having it in or out makes no difference.  Good thought though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a configuration issue; the configuration of php on the servers I was using did not have soap enabled.  Additionally, I did not have admin permissions on the servers, so it was difficult to determine this as the cause and then impossible to fix.

I had to set up my own machine as a server, and I am now able to successfully set up a SoapClient.

If anyone else goes through something similar and needs to do the same thing, I found a good tutorial on how to set up an Apache server on a Windows machine with PHP and MySQL here: http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=272080

Comment: I want to construct a soap request in php, please see the sample request format,,  <soap:Body>
   <wsdl:ConfigurationType>
   <wsdl:Configuration chekType="0">
   <kk:Addr>Primary</kk:Addr>

Answer (score 0):

Construct your SoapClient like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
```

You need the trace option to be able to see the output of `__getLastRequest()`

Comment: That certainly makes sense, but it hasn't fixed my problem. I added your code to my code (as shown above), with the object dump lines uncommented, and the browser still shows only the object dump, not the functions dump.  It would appear that execution of the PHP code just halts after trying to call any function on the $client variable.

Comment: Ah: should `type1`/`type2`/`mynamespace` (used in your `SoapVar` constructor calls) be `$type1`/`$type2`/`$mynamespace` or perhaps `'type1'`/`'type2'`/`'mynamespace'` (i.e. either variables or strings) or have they been `DEFINED` somewhere else?

Comment: No. Sorry for that confusion; those placeholders are just for the purposes of this post, in my code those are actually string literals.

Comment: Oh ok. Well, I'd fall back to good old `echo` debugging: put an `echo` statement after every line and see which specific line is the last one to successfully complete. That and I'd check your PHP error logs to see if you have an error logged somewhere offscreen.

Comment: I have somewhat done the echo debugging; from the following code snippet:

`$wsdl = ...;
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

    echo("\nDumping client object:\n");
    var_dump($client);

    echo("\nDumping client object functions:\n");
    var_dump($client->__getFunctions());`

The last thing to be printed is "Dumping client object functions:"

Can you tell me where I can find the PHP error logs?

Comment: Typically it should dump to Apache's error log. I'd put the `echo` statements before and after the `SoapVar` constructor calls. Those might be failing.

Comment: I don't think execution is even getting to the `SoapVar` constructor calls; as I say it isn't even printing the object functions dump.

Comment: Ah. Might be an error in your WSDL. Try retrieving it directly from the source?

Comment: I didn't create the wsdl; I'm pretty sure there aren't any errors in it.

Comment: Ah, alright, but...I know that `SoapClient` works when presented with proper WSDL, so either a) your system is broken b) the WSDL that is being retrieved is incorrect somehow. Perhaps there is authorization required to get the correct WSDL from the source

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "your system is broken"?

Comment: Well, you do not appear to have explicit syntax errors in the code you have provided, so either there is some error in the specific copy of the SoapClient library on the server you are running this code on (which is what I mean by broken). Barring extreme circumstances, this is more unlikely. What is more likely is that you are somehow passing erroneous WSDL to the SoapClient or there is some communication failure reaching the server running the web service.

Comment: Interesting.  Well as I say, I tested the wsdl call in SoapUI, so I'm pretty sure that's correct.  What are the possibilities for a communication failure, other than an authorization issue?

Comment: Not really sure: maybe there is some other URL that needs to be resolved within the WSDL. Without the WSDL it would be hard to tell.